# QFile Unicode path - file does not exist

Tags: qt, unicode, path, urldecode, qfile

I write a [Firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-mp3-podcaster/) that calls out to external programs to get work done :). The trouble is Firefox can't handle Unicode when you're passing arguments, so I'm having to jump through some hoops when I call my exes.

What I've been doing is using URI encoded strings instead, and I'm using the QT library to do the hard stuff of handling Unicode Strings. But I can't get QT's QFile to find anything on a Unicode path.

I start with a string like this:

C:\temp\私\Power Up!.mp3

I encode it into this:

C%3A%5Ctemp%5C%E7%A7%81%5CPower%20Up!.mp3

Then I pass it as a command line argument. Right now I'm passing it in the Visual C++ 2010 Express Edition compiler's Debugging Command Line Arguments.

Finally I try to do this:

```
std::string fileName( "c:\\temp\\debug " );
std::string extension (".txt");
ofstream a_file ( fileName + extension );
QString filepath ( argv[argc - 1] );

QString url = QUrl::fromPercentEncoding( filepath.toUtf8() ).replace("\\","/");

a_file << "Param: " << url.replace("\\","/").toStdString()  << "\n\n";

QFile myQfile ( url.replace("\\","/") ); // Replacing every backslash with a forward slash 
                                         // QT doesn't allow backslashes in paths.

if( !myQfile.exists() ){
    a_file << "The param \""  << myQfile.fileName().toStdString() << "\" is not a file.";
    a_file.close();
    exit(1);
}//END IF
```

If I don't have a path with a '私' character it works fine, but otherwise the call to exists() returns false and I end up exiting out. I know the file is there though, and when I check my debug file in notepad++ it has the right characters.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:

I think I may have got it.

First I switched to a wmain like so:

```
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
```

Then I set up my QStrings like so:

```
QString filepath = QString::fromWCharArray ( argv[argc - 1] );

QString url = QUrl::fromPercentEncoding( filepath.toLocal8Bit() );

TagLib::FileRef f( url.toStdWString().c_str() );
```

This works so far. I need to do some more testing :), and I'm 90% sure this won't compile in Linux/OSX (I need to build QT in Linux to find out, and look into the wchar_t macro).

Comment: "QT doesn't allow backslashes in paths" - that's wrong, Qt allows both `/` and `\`. As '/' works on all platforms, it's recommended though.

Comment: Sorry, should Have specified I'm on QT 4.8. That said, the docs I found here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfile.html had the line "QFile expects the file separator to be '/' regardless of operating system"... I've tried it without the replace though and I still can't get it to work :(

Comment: Are url and filepath correct?

Comment: They should be. When I write the url variable out to a file and open the file in notepad++ I get what I expect (e.g. the string "Param: C:\temp\私\Power Up!.mp3"). Even regular notepad.exe displays it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a shot in the dark, but would I suggest you try removing the exclamation mark from the filename or replace it with %21

All the debugger does is run the program in hidden console using batch script. If it happens to be the case that (and it usually is) your system's Command Processor has "Delayed Environment Variable Expansion" set to ON by default, then the '!' will be discarded from the command line.

- Alan

P.S.

This setting can be found in the registry and turned off locally or globally:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\DelayedExpansion
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\DelayedExpansion

P.P.S.
**You may also need to replace % with %% for similar reasons.**

Comment: I think I might have got it. For starters I switched to a 'wmain' like so: 

    int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])

Then I set up my Qstrings like this:

     QString filepath = QString::fromWCharArray ( argv[argc - 1] );
 
     QString url = QUrl::fromPercentEncoding( filepath.toLocal8Bit() );

Comment: Whatever works I guess. I don't know anything about Qstring or firefox plugins, but I do know that what happens under the VC debugger using its "command line arguments" feature can't be trusted to indicate what will happen in "the real world" so to speak. [P.S. You might consider a "const" modifier somewhere before that first '*', unless you plan to edit the command line (which is what your declaration indicates)]